# Undesired colorbox reload in a drupal behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, colorbox

I'm creating a colorbox which prompts everytime a user logs in. I've got the backend working but when I'm trying to create the colorbox I've been facing several problems. First of all, I couldn't create the colorbox on page load because "I think" I was fetching some data and that was causing that the colorbox empty, so I've added a delay and a hidden link to be triggered after some time. But now the problem that I've is that the click event is triggered in an infinite loop and crashes the site.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.beerfactory = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        var state = Drupal.settings.mhf_login_popup.message_state;
        var message = Drupal.settings.mhf_login_popup.message_content;
        if (state) {
            $("#login-popup").colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", html:message});
            var id = setTimeout(function(){
                $("#login-popup").click();
            }, 1000);
        };

    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Is there any workaround on this? or something I'm missing?

### Edit

I've removed the click triggering and replaced for:

```
        var id = setTimeout(function(){
          $.colorbox({width:"900px", height:"600px", html:message});
        }, 1000);
```

With this change the colorbox prompts without triggering the click event but even though the colorbox keeps realoading in an infinite loop. Can it be a something related to drupal behaviours or some colorbox parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a script on my theme without drupal behaviours. I've seen that the conflict that I had was caused because of the ajax of the colorbox and the drupal behaviours. I should filter that using context or once() but I don't know how.

[Reference](https://drupal.org/node/1933956)